# How to install Foundation in Rails Engine 4.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, zurb-foundation

It seems that foundation doesn't seem to "play nicely" with rails engines. I am designing a style layout engine so that I can plug and play this engine into various backend apps. I would love to use foundation to do the design work but no matter what different installation techniques I try, I still seem to get the same errors:

I initially tried running:

```
$rails g foundation:install
```

which returned:

```
"could not find generator foundation:install"
```

I double checked my bundle, because I added zurb-foundation to my gemspec file. It was in my bundle, so I figured it was a compatibility problem with me using a rails engine instead of a regular rails app. To which I found this article: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1225

I tried following @ivansnek's directions. Which gave me these errors in my chrome console:

```
foundation.js?body=1:26 Uncaught TypeError
foundation.alerts.js?body=1:58 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.clearing.js?body=1:517 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.cookie.js?body=1:75 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.dropdown.js?body=1:184 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.forms.js?body=1:556 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.joyride.js?body=1:853 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.magellan.js?body=1:137 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.orbit.js?body=1:432 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.reveal.js?body=1:354 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.section.js?body=1:431 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.tooltips.js?body=1:210 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.topbar.js?body=1:371 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.interchange.js?body=1:281 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
foundation.abide.js?body=1:195 Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined
application.js?body=1:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I then tried the regular ol' manual installation guide on foundation's documentation here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html
which gave me the same errors listed above. Has anyone run into these problems, and can point me in the direction of the right documentation, or explain to me how you successfully installed foundation into a rails engine? As an ending note, foundation seems to be working just fine in my dummy app. It's just in my actual engine where I can't get it to play nicely. In my dummy app, I was able to run the foundation install generator successfully. My actual engine requires a manual installation instead of a rails generator.

**EDIT:**

I added the gem 'foundation-rails'. So now I have the zurb-foundation gem AND the foundation-rails gem included in my engine. This got rid of the 'Uncaught ReferenceError' errors I was getting. But now the reference to jQuery is not working. My google console error says "jQuery is not defined." This leads me to believe that the manual installation is still not going well. I am referencing foundation in my application.js like:

```
//= require foundation
$(document).foundation();
```

Comment: "$ is not defined" -> Do you have the jQuery in your application.js like you should?

Comment: I´m a bit confused as to whats going wrong and what you are looking to achieve. Are your end users going to add your gem and then run the `foundation:install` generator? Or does your app have a generator which in turn calls the foundation generator?

Comment: My engine's install generator will call the foundation generator. What I am trying to achieve is creating a template engine with a front end that I can plug into various apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue with foundation-rails not being able to install correctly into rails mountable engines. I am currently submitting a pull request and will update this answer once a solution comes about.

Answer (score 1):

First off - get rid of the `zurb-foundation` gem. It is dead (last release was 2013) and having two different versions of Foundation in your gem is just going to cause headaches.

I recently encountered this issue with foundation-rails 5.5.1.1 in a normal rails app. It seems to be due to a bug where plugins are required before foundation/foundation (the "core") which is [fixed in a commit](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/commit/2e380a3578f2723bc5e9ef5f49866b0adee24bcb) but has not yet been released.

You can either use the master branch off github:

```
gem 'foundation-rails', github: "zurb/foundation-rails"
```

Or require 'foundation/foundation' before 'foundation' in your sprockets manifest:

```
//= require 'jquery'
//= require 'foundation/foundation' 
//= require 'foundation'
```

Comment: Foundation-Rails still does not play nicely with rails engines however. I am marking your answer as correct, because foundation-rails is the appropriate gem to use. However, we need a version that will have an install generator that works with namespacing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the following line in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'zurb-foundation'
```

After that you have to run the `bundle` command. Then try again to

```
rails g foundation:install
```

Comment: If you refer back to my question details: I initially tried running:

$rails g foundation:install 
which returned:

"could not find generator foundation:install" 
I double checked my bundle, because I added zurb-foundation to my gemspec file. It was in my bundle, successfully. But the generator still does not work.